# Operation to remove matches from list?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any operation in linq that works along the lines of ...

```
IEnumerable<...> removed = myList.RemoveWhere([filter])
```

I only found `RemoveAll` which just returns a number (which is not very helpful) and `Except` which just takes another list.

EDIT: so I was asked for a better use case (understandable). My use case basically is: I have a list of objects that should be grouped based on certain properties. These groups do not overlap so once an element is part of a group it can't be part of any other. This also means, doing stuff like

```
var group1 = list.Where(...)
var group2 = list.Where(...)
...
```

is a huge waste of time (because it goes through the same items again and again even though they are of no use any more. Thus it would make sense to remove filtered-out elements from the list.

And now thinking about it, I will try something with ToLookup or GroupBy even if that means the grouping condition will be ugly as hell.

Comment: Eh, `.Where(item => condition)`? Since it looks that you want just a *repsentation* of the `myList` (*as if* some items are removed)

Comment: Probably your best bet is going to be to build an interim list which you then iterate over to actually perform the removes.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko so maybe to describe by problem better: I have a list of elements and want to group/filter them based on different conditions (that do not overlap). Yes, I could do "where" everywhere, but that would mean having to search through elements that I already _know_ won't match.

Comment: Well, could you give us a better use case, how will the final selection be used? Is `NotifyPropertyChanged` needed? Can we replace the list? Are the filters changing? Since you are removing those you don't need rather than selection those you want I am very confused.

Comment: @flindeberg edited ... and I realized I could maybe use another method altogether

Answer (score 2):

> To get removed elements from the list.

You have to invert your filter and get the elements. You can't get removed elements after removing them using `List<T>.RemoveAll`. There are multiple things you can do:

1. Invert your filter.

Code:

```
var toBeRemovedItems = myList.Where(r=> !(yourFilter)); //.ToList() to get a list back
```

2. The other approach could be to keep a copy of the list , and then remove from the original list and use `Except` to get the difference *(should be avoided as it is confusing and memory consuming)*.

---

[`List.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) does return the number of elements removed from the list and **it also removes the element from the List.**

You can use that like:

```
myList.RemoveAll([filter])
```

This will modify the list in place.

But this is only available with `List<T>`, if you want to work with `IEnumerable<T>` then you can filter out the values using `Where` and then assign the result back:

```
var result  = yourList.Where(r=> r != yourCondition);
```

and if you want a new list then you can append `ToList` to it.

Comment: as I said, I want the removed elements from my list, not a count

Comment: @FrankyBoy, ohhh, In that case you have to invert your filter and get the elements.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing I've seen like that, but you can do it with a few lines of code:

```
var removed = list.Where(x => Filter(x)).ToList();
list.RemoveAll(x => removed.Contains(x));
```

`removed` will keep the elements because of the `.ToList()` (otherwise, you'd still be working on the list items, which is modified because of `.RemoveAll()`). Another option is just to have a `Where(x => Filter(x))` and the opposite `Where(x => !Filter(x))`.

If you wanted it to be shorter, you can make your own extension method.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will go this way, though it again means touching each list element a few times which is not super awesome. Maybe some sort of indexing operation (I forgot how its called, not GroupBy, the other) would work best as a basis for this method actually. EDIT: toLookup is what I meant.

Comment: `GroupBy` might work, where you just group on filtered true or false, and then you get each group. This isn't as understandable in my opinion, but it might be faster internally. I'm not familiar with `ToLookup`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Where` clause with the logical negation of your condition to return only those elements whose values don't mean the condition:

```
IEnumerable<...> removed = myList.Where( x => ![filter])
```